# Draw a Line Between Two Points described by Trigonometric Calculations

Tags: tikz-pgf, coordinates, draw

Suppose I have two points the unit circle corresponding to 30 and 60 degrees from the x-axis.

I want to draw a line between these two points.

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}  
\usepackage{calculator}  
\usetikzlibrary{rulercompass}  
\usetikzlibrary{intersections,quotes,angles}  
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}  
\begin{tikzpicture}  
  \draw (\cos(30), \sin(30)) -- (\cos(60), \sin(60));  
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

But this does not execute.

What is the correct way?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You're *almost* there. Two things to fix:

1. `\cos` is a macro defined to typeset `cos`. To have PGF parse it as the cosine function you have to remove the backslash and let it parse the three letters `c`, `o`, `s` as the function name.
2. When Ti*k*Z looks for coordinates it uses delimited macros, so when you do `(cos(30), sin(30))` it will look for something between `(` and the next `)`, which is `cos(30`, and things will go weird :). To avoid this you can "hide" the parentheses in braces: `({cos(30)}, {sin(30)})`.

then it will work:

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{calculator}
\usetikzlibrary{rulercompass}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections,quotes,angles}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw ({cos(30)}, {sin(30)}) -- ({cos(60)}, {sin(60)});
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 8):

<sub>An addition, the question is already answered and explained by Phelype Oleinik.</sub>

TikZ also supports polar coordinates. Thus, the example can be reduced to

```
\documentclass[border=5mm, tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
  \tikz\draw (30:1) -- (60:1);
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Answer (score 3):

A PSTricks solution just for fun!

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\pspicture(-1,-1)(1,1)
\psline(1;30)(1;60)
\endpspicture
\end{document}
```